# Escaped value ('\s) in database

Tags: php, security, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter, and what I do is basically:

```
$val = $this->db->call_function('real_escape_string', $this->input->post('name'));
```

this is all I do on data before putting into database. And when someone enters value like O'hara, in database it will appear like O\'hara

So, I guess I can string slashes on output, but is this usual way of escaping and storing data in database?

**SOLVED**
Active Records escapes the query, so I do double escaping, with 'real_escape_string' function as well

So I guess I don't need to use real_escape_string at all, active records does this

Comment: Maybe you have magic quotes enabled? And please search our site for the myriad of discussions on proper database escaping.

Comment: no not enabled I checked. One more info, I use Active records, but STILL I skimmed thorough functions and can't see that this is escaping data ( like double escape and than / gets stored). And thanks, will check all other infos for storing values in db

Answer (score 1):

The '\' is called an escape character and must be used so the next character after it (in your case ') won't interfere with the SQL statement. However, if you're using CI, it should take care of all of this for you. There's an 'HTML helper' that I believe you can use to format or take out the slashes on outputted text. Even then, but I could be wrong, when outputting values from a DB in CI, the slashes will automatically be stripped.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping quotes and special characters is both regular practice and expected for record storage as it helps to ensure that your code can be accurately stored and extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the strings for the SQL query is so that you can get the actual values into the database.

The value in the SQL query will look like `O\'hara` but the value that ends up in the database is `O'hara`.

So, you don't have to do anything at all when you display the value. Except escaping it for the environment where you display it of course. If it's displayed in a HTML document, you would HTML encode it. This will not change the apostrope (`'`), but it will change other characters, like `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

use directly

```
$val = real_escape_string($this->input->post('name'));
```